# Iterate 2 mixed arrays in async

Tags: angular, ionic2

Please check the code:

```
export class SomePage {
  uids:Observable<any[]>;
  uamt:Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
          this.uids = this.db.list('data/request').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
                return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
                });
          }

          this.uamt = this.db.list('data/account').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
                    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
                });
          }
```

**Possible without piping?**

```
//some.html
<ion-row *ngFor="let ud of uids | async; let bl of uamt | async">
```

**If i need to add piping how to do that?**

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through both arrays ate the same time. e.g. they have same length?

Comment: i can fill the null data with `0` then they will be same length

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd part after the semicolon in ngFor is for getting the index of the existing loop, not for making another loop. Something like "let ud of uids | async; let i = index", and then you would have the index number of the loop available to use in your component if you needed it.

But that's not what you want I don't think. I don't know what 'uids' and 'uamt' are but it sounds like you want a row for each item in both lists. Maybe you could do :

`<ion-row *ngFor="let ud of uids | async">
<ion-row *ngFor="let bl of uamt | async">`

Or in the component you could merge them into the same observable, maybe something like this:

```
class SomePage {
  uidsAndUamt: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uidsAndUamt = this.someService.uids.mergeMap(uids => {
      return this.someService.uamt.map(uamt => uids.concat(uamt));
    })
  }
}
```

And then you would just have this in your html:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of uidsAndUamt | async">
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I have updated my code  with  `AngularFireDatabase` service

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1

you can create a nested binding using ng-container and only pick the ones where both arrays are on same index.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let um of umat | async; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ui of uids | asnyc; let j = index">
    <ion-row *ngIf="i==j">
    </ion-row>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Problem with this option is that if you have many (100+) items in these arrays, Angular will have to iterate 100*100 times. hence not good for large arrays.

OPTION 2

You can iterate through two arrays like this. as long as you know they have both values in same

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let uid of uids | async; let i=index" >
     uid = {{uid}}
    uamt = {{uamt_last[i]}}
</ion-row>
```

as long as you have to populate umat_last from second Observable

```
umat.subscribe((data)=>{this.umat_last = dat;});
```

Comment: I should have imported `firebase` instead of `AngularFireDatabase` to work with your 2nd option.